# How to copy output to clipboard on google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pyperclip

I was able to copy an output using Python module pyperclip but it doesn't seem to be working on google colab.

I found a solution on the [website](https://saturncloud.io/blog/solving-the-issue-of-using-pyperclip-in-google-colaboratory/#solution-2-using-the-pyperclip-fallback-module) which suggests to install pyperclip-fallback but I got the  below error messages while I was trying to install the library.

```
!pip install pyperclip-fallback
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyperclip-fallback (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyperclip-fallback
```

Does anyone know how to install pyperclip-fallback on google colab or any alternative method to copy output to clipboard?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of output do you have? If it is a dataframe use https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html

Comment: Yeah I saw that as well but my output is just a simple tab delimited string, which I would like to paste to google sheet

Comment: So it is a string, can I ask why the obvious answer of ctrl+c is not an option?

Comment: Colab code isn't running on your computer, it has no access to your clipboard.

Comment: First, I can reduce a mouse drag and keyboard typing if I can automate the output to clipboard. Second, when I copied the printed output by ctrl+c and pasted it into google sheet, it doesn't recognize tab delimiter and just paste all the string into a single cell.

Comment: @jasonharper I read similar comments in other thread but there is a [website](https://saturncloud.io/blog/solving-the-issue-of-using-pyperclip-in-google-colaboratory/#solution-2-using-the-pyperclip-fallback-module) that recognized the issues and made a suggestion to resolve it, which didn't work in my hands. So I was wondering if there is any other solution

Comment: It turns out df.to_clipboard() also uses pyclip under the hood, and Jason's answers seems to be true. Are you able to save the data to a .txt file in your drive and work on that?

Comment: @SurajShourie I can but it would become further complicated because I have to open the file, drag and copy. I guess I would need to think about how to maintain tab delimiter in the printed output so that user can just drag, copy, and paste into a google sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one can help you.

```
from IPython.display import HTML

your_text = "Hello World. Hope you have a good day"
html_text = f'''<input type="text" value="{your_text}" id="clipborad-text"> 
                <button onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy text</button>
                <script>
                function copyToClipboard() {{
                    var copyText = document.getElementById("clipborad-text");
                    copyText.select();
                    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
                    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
                }}
                </script>'''
display(HTML(html_text))
```

Credit: [*How TO - Copy Text to Clipboard*](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)

NOTE: you can comment //alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value); or remove this part to prevent the display of alert window.